# Table View Cells are not reaching to same array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to build an app which has object of Items and a controller for it which is called ItemsController. Also on my screen I suppose to have a table view and a button on it. The functionality of button is when it is clicked it needs to check favoriteItems array in ItemsController if it is found in that array remove element, if it isn't found there then append it to array. Operations for remove and append good but unfortunately all cells are not working together. They creates their own favoriteItems array.

To achieve this I tried to make ItemsController to be a singleton. I changed class to a struct and called ItemsController.sharedInstance everywhere. It actually solved a lot of my problem and I believe that the source I learnt this is not wrong about it. But why my tableview cells doesn't use ItemsController's favoriteItems array instead create theirs?

```
struct ItemsController {
    var favoriteItems = [Items]()
    static var sharedInstance = ItemsController()

    init(){
        itemsArray = [...items...]
    }
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var favoriteButton: UIButton!

let buttonFirstColor : UIColor = UIColor.clear
let buttonSecondColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 224/255.0, green: 74/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
var itemsController = ItemsController.sharedInstance
var itemDedicated = Items(name: "", pic: "", aciklama: "")

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    favoriteButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * favoriteButton.bounds.size.width
    favoriteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    favoriteButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 224/255.0, green: 74/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    favoriteButton.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
    favoriteButton.clipsToBounds = true

    setFavoriteButton()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func favoriteButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    var favoriteFound = false

    for items in itemsController.favoriteItems{
        if(items.name == itemDedicated.name){
            favoriteFound = true            }
    }

    if(favoriteFound){
        itemsController.favoriteItems.remove(at: itemsController.favoriteItems.index(of: itemDedicated)!)
    } else {
        itemsController.favoriteItems.append(itemDedicated)
    }

    setFavoriteButton()
}

private func setFavoriteButton(){
    var favoriteFound = false

    for items in itemsController.favoriteItems{
        if(items.name == itemDedicated.name){
            favoriteFound = true            }
    }

    if(favoriteFound){
        favoriteButton.backgroundColor = buttonSecondColor
        favoriteButton.setTitleColor(buttonFirstColor, for: .normal)
    } else {
        favoriteButton.backgroundColor = buttonFirstColor
        favoriteButton.setTitleColor(buttonFirstColor, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add your current code

Comment: Code added. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean they create their own array?

Comment: When I put print(itemsController.favoriteItems.count) into favoriteButtonClicked() and when I click different cells' favoriteButton it prints 1 (which means it adds to array) and when I hit favoriteButton of same cell it prints 0 (which mean it removes) But these are local changes not global changes. If I hit 2 different cells' favoriteButton then it should print 2 not 1. Because the count of itemsController.favoriteItems should be 2.

Comment: I think I need to use let instead of var in the declaration of itemsController but then I cannot append or remove items to favoriteItems array. Xcode says "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'itemsController' is a 'let' constant"

Comment: Your cell should not be tracking state or updating the model directly. That is the job of the view controller.  Also, a singleton `struct` doesn't make sense, since structs are value types. As soon as a cell modifies `itemsController`, Swift will make a copy of the struct and modify *that*. You could create mutating functions on your struct to manipulate the array, but really, none of this logic belong in your cell class.

Comment: I understand. I tried to keep thing cleaner. So I thought doing that is Table View Cell's job. Firstly I made it on view controller, then I tried to move it table view cell. Thank you for brief explanation.